# Manage TFS 2013 Permissions

Tags: tfs

I have a need to create a new Project Collection that can't be seen by specific  members of the TFS Administrators group.  I figured that I could just explicitly deny the users access to the project collection, but this documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms252587(v=vs.110).aspx) states that being in the Admin group would override any explicit deny permission.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Administrators can see everything in TFS, so I'm not aware of any way to prevent their access.

(A better model would be that admins are restricted to creating collections, but not administer or view data within them without granting themselves special permissions to do so - which could be recorded and notified to the collection admins. Or collection admins could choose to lock out the site admins)

One approach is to create a domain account to be your TFS admin, to restrict access or accidental use of a collection, but that would not be enough to stop an authorised admin user being able to access your collection if they wished to. However, if you create a whole new server instance for your protected collection, you could use a different admin account to properly deny access to unauthorised admins.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.

You would need to create a seperate TFS instance that did not have those people as admins.

Note: Your server admins should not be TFS Admins. Operations should own the hardware and OS at most and never the applications.